# What is the utility of a bool variable in C?

Tags: c, variables, boolean

What is the advantage of using bool variable in the code below instead of an int to set the value 1 or 0? What difference does it make?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int p,d;
    _Bool isPrime;

    for ( p = 2; p <= 50; p++){
        isPrime = 1;

        for (d = 2; d < p; d++)
            if (p %d == 0)
                isPrime = 0;

        if (isPrime != 0)
            printf("%i ",p);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful for making your intent clear. When you declare a variable as `Bool_`, it's obvious it's never supposed to have a value other than `true` and `false`.

A more conventional way to write your example code would be:

#include

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int p = 2; p <= 50; p++) {
        bool isPrime = true;

        for (int d = 2; d < p; d++) {
            if (p % d == 0) isPrime = false;
        }

        if (!isPrime) printf("%i ", p);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could they have some impact on the execution speed, since they are small in size and contains only 0 or 1?

Comment: @user1825355 It's a priori *fantastically* unlikely that changing between two data types that do the same and use the same amount of memory will have any effect on performance at all. Even if it did, it's still pretty unlikely that this would make your program appreciably slow. If anything, using `_Bool` gives the optimiser more to work with. If you care about performance, **measure first** to find out where your program is spending time, then **eliminate bottlenecks**. Modern optimizers and CPU architectures are too complex to let you say that changing one line of code makes a program slower.

Comment: so can we say that using bool variable only improves the readability of the source code?

Comment: @user1825355 I'd argue that it does.

Comment: @user1825355 Consider especially the convention where some system calls return an *error code*, and use an outparam for the actual result value. An error code of `0` usually means success. If you return `int` from both functions that follow that convention, and from functions that return a `true` or a `false`, it's not immediately obvious what should be done with the return value to test for a positive result. (`if (result)` or `if (result == SUCCESS)`.) If you use `_Bool` for the second kind, you only need to look at the function signature to know what values you'll get and what they mean.

Comment: @tobi303 I was copy-pasting the OP's code and missed that, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

I just use plain ints as my boolean type without any typedefs or special defines or enums for true/false values. If you follow my suggestion below on never comparing against boolean constants, then you only need to use 0/1 to initialize the flags anyway. However, such an approach may be deemed too reactionary in these modern times. In that case, one should definitely use  since it at least has the benefit of being standardized.

Whatever the boolean constants are called, use them only for initialization. Never ever write something like

```
if (ready == TRUE) ...
while (empty == FALSE) ...
```

These can always be replaced by the clearer

if (ready) ...
while (!empty) ...
Note that these can actually reasonably and understandably be read out loud.

Give your boolean variables positive names, ie full instead of notfull. The latter leads to code that is difficult to read easily. Compare

```
if (full) ...
if (!full) ...
```

with

```
if (!notfull) ...
if (notfull) ...
```

Both of the former pair read naturally, while !notfull is awkward to read even as it is, and becomes much worse in more complex boolean expressions.

Boolean arguments should generally be avoided. Consider a function defined like this

```
void foo(bool option) { ... }
```

Within in the body of the function, it is very clear what the argument means since it has a convenient, and hopefully meaningful, name. But, the call sites look like

```
foo(TRUE);
foo(FALSE):
```

Here, it's essentially impossible to tell what the parameter mean without always looking at the function definition or declaration, and it gets much worse as soon if you add even more boolean parameters.. I suggest either

```
typedef enum { OPT_ON, OPT_OFF } foo_option;
void foo(foo_option option);
```

or

```
#define OPT_ON true
#define OPT_OFF false
void foo(bool option) { ... }
```

In either case, the call site now looks like

```
foo(OPT_ON);
foo(OPT_OFF);
```

which the reader has at least a chance of understanding without dredging up the definition of foo.

Comment: Well, this goes off on a tangent. I have an suggestion to add: if you have a function that logically calls for many boolean parameters, I believe it's conventional to use a bitmask instead.